# knockout array radio button and/or droplist based

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Right now I am populating radio button from the observable array,

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cars">
  <div>
      <input type='radio' data-bind="checked: $root.vehicle, checkedValue: id, value:id"><span data-bind="text: model"></span>
  </div>
</div>

 Model data,

 public class MyViewModel
 {
     public List<Cars> cars {get; set;}
 }
 public class Cars
 {
     public int Id{get; set;}
     public string Make {get; set;}
     public string Model {get; set;} 
 }
```

Say if I want to populated radio button for Make 'Honda' and dropdown list for make 'Toyota'. How to do that?

Basically, I am trying populate two different list of controls from same observable array.

Comment: Do you want whichever vehicle is selected , then its models get populated as a dropDown option ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what exactly you want to do, here is an example through what you could do : 
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/85/

HTML :

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: Cars">
        <input type='radio' data-bind="checked :$parent.VehicleSelected ,checkedValue: Make, value:Id">
        <span data-bind="text: Make"></span>
        <select data-bind="foreach:Models,visible:IsSelected" >
          <option data-bind="text:Name , value:Id"></option>
        </select>
        <br />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var data = [
{Id:1,Make :"TOYOTA",Model: [{Id:1,Name:"COROLLA"},{Id:2,Name:"CAMERY"},{Id:3,Name:"PERADO"}]},
{Id:2,Make :"HONDA",Model:[{Id:4,Name:"CIVIC"},{Id:5,Name:"ACCORD"},{Id:6,Name:"PILOT"}]},
{Id:3,Make :"NISSAN",Model:[{Id:7,Name:"SENTRA"},{Id:8,Name:"ALTIMA"},{Id:9,Name:"JUKE"}]}];

function AppViewModel() {
 var self = this ;
 self.Cars = ko.observableArray($.map(data, function (item) {
      return new CarItemViewModel(item);
 }));
  self.VehicleSelected = ko.observable();
  self.VehicleSelected.subscribe(function(newValue){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Cars(), function(item) {
        if (item.Make().toUpperCase() === newValue.toUpperCase()) {
            return item.IsSelected(true);
        }else{
           return item.IsSelected(false);
        }
    });
  })

}

var CarItemViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this ;
  self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.Make = ko.observable(data.Make);
  self.Models = ko.observableArray($.map(data.Model, function (item) {
    return new ModelsItemViewModel(item);
  }));
  self.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);
}
var ModelsItemViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this ;
  self.Id = data.Id;
  self.Name = data.Name;
}
var appVM = new AppViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(appVM);
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question:

- You have one variable that holds all your data
- You want to render *multiple* UI elements that represent sub-sets of these data

A good way to do this is by using `ko.computed`s that return the filtered result of an `observableArray`. An example:

```
var allCars = ko.observableArray([
  {"name":"CIVIC","make":"HONDA"},
  {"name":"SENTRA","make":"NISSAN"}];

var hondas = ko.computed(function() {
  return allCars().filter(function(car) {
    return car.make === "HONDA";
  });
});
```

Because the computed uses the `allCars` observable, it is notified when the source data changes. The `filter` method is re-evaluated. In the snippet below you can see that you can push new data to your source and is automatically put in the right subset!

```js
var allCars = ko.observableArray([
  {"name":"CIVIC","make":"HONDA"},
  {"name":"ACCORD","make":"HONDA"},
  {"name":"PILOT","make":"HONDA"},
  {"name":"SENTRA","make":"NISSAN"},
  {"name":"ALTIMA","make":"NISSAN"},
  {"name":"JUKE","make":"NISSAN"}]);

var hondas = ko.computed(function() {
  return allCars().filter(function(car) {
    return car.make === "HONDA";
  });
});

var nissans = ko.computed(function() {
  return allCars().filter(function(car) {
    return car.make === "NISSAN";
  });
});

var otherBrands = ko.computed(function() {
  return allCars().filter(function(car) {
      return car.make !== "NISSAN" &&
        car.make !== "HONDA";
  });
});

var inputVM = {
  name: ko.observable(""),
  make: ko.observable(""),
  add: function() {
     allCars.push({
       name: this.name(),
       make: this.make().toUpperCase()
     }); 
  }
};

ko.applyBindings({ 
  hondas: hondas, 
  nissans: nissans,
  allCars: allCars,
  otherBrands: otherBrands,
  inputVM: inputVM
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Honda</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: hondas">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<h2>Nissan</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: nissans">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<h2>Other brands</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: otherBrands">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<h2>Add car</h2>
<div data-bind="with: inputVM">
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Make:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: make">
  </label>
  <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
</div>
```